# How to select all rows that share a maximum value in a column using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | user_id |     start_date      |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2014-02-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 |       1 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  3 |       2 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  4 |       2 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  5 |       3 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

how can I select all rows that, for each user, have:

- start date before NOW() and
- maximum start_date

so for sample rows, the output should be:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | user_id |     start_date      |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2014-02-01 00:00:00 | // this is a single maximum date within that user
|  3 |       2 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | // these two share maximum start date
|  4 |       2 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

what I have so far is something like this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM ticket t
    JOIN (
        SELECT start_date, MAX(start_date) FROM ticket /* GROUP BY user_id */
    ) highest
    ON t.start_date = highest.start_date
    WHERE t.start_date <= NOW();
```

but this doesn't work as desired. Am I on good path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, sort of.
In your derived table, you need to get the max date for each user id, so:

```
SELECT user_id, 
      MAX(start_date) as MaxDate
      FROM ticket 
      GROUP BY user_id
```

Then you can join to that on start date and user id:

```
SELECT t.* FROM ticket t
    JOIN (
      SELECT user_id, 
      MAX(start_date) as MaxDate
      FROM ticket 
      GROUP BY user_id
    ) highest
    ON t.start_date = highest.maxdate
  and t.user_id = highest.user_id
    WHERE t.start_date <= NOW();
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/367ea/5)

Answer (score 0):

_try this:

```
SELECT T.* FROM ticket AS T
JOIN (SELECT
     [User_Id]
    ,MAX([Start_Date])  AS Start_Date
FROM ticket
WHERE Start_Date <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY User_Id) AS Grouped    ON T.User_Id = Grouped.User_Id AND T.Start_Date = Grouped.Start_Date
ORDER BY Id
DROP TABLE #This
```